# Multiple regexes/masks in Sprout Field validation

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

Is there a way to include multiple validation masks in Sprout Fields? I've tried to do this (for my phone number validation):

```
#### ####|### ## ###
```

Since both of those are valid. If I try to write it out as a real regular expression, like this:

```
^([0-9]{4}) ([0-9]{4})|([0-9]{3}) ([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{3})$
```

it just fails: `preg_match(): Empty regular expression`

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Sprout Fields Phone Field only supports a single mask.

If you need more advanced pattern support, a Regex Field Type is probably the way to go.

Here is one that came up in my search:

- [mn_matchinput](https://github.com/marionnewlevant/craft-mn_matchinput)